# App Cache for HTML5 is not downloading

Tags: html, browser-cache

Trying to implement offline ability with my web application so added the `.appchache` file and it looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#css
css/global.css
#js
js/scripts.js
js/jquery.js
js/jquery.min.map
# last-update 9/4/2013
```

saved it as `cache.appchache` and then added it to to index.html like so `<html lang="en-US" manifest="cache.appcache">`

Then added MIME type `.appcache` to be served as `text/cache-manifest` on IIS

Then I reloaded my index.html page a few times and then opened `chrome://appcache-internals/` to look at my server's cache and it was not in there.

Opened up the console in google chrome and it stated: Application Cache Error event: `Manifest fetch failed (404)`

tried opening the manifest by URL and I get a 404. Then I went to the `file://location_of_cache/cache.appcache` and it popped up.

Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, IIS does not serve files that it does not recognize, and while I added text/cache-manifest to the server mime types I did not add it to the specific website. Went into IIS click properties on the website I was using -> http headers -> mime types -> added .appcache and then reloaded my browser and everything worked.